# Angular Model Isn't Updated When Input Is Changed

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular UI bootstrap to create a modal

I have this template

```
<div class="modal-body">
Topic <input type="text" ng-model="topic" />
<div id="topic-error" class="field-validation-error" ng-show="error" ng-bind="error">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" ng-disabled="!topic">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Then this is the modal controller

```
app.controller('AddTopicCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance','$http',
 function ($scope, $modalInstance,$http) {

     $scope.topic = 'initial';
     $scope.error = "";
     $scope.ok = function () {

         $http.post("/api/topics/post", { name: $scope.topic })
             .success(function(result) {
                 if (result.Status == "Ok") {

                     $modalInstance.close(result.Data.Topic);
                 } else {
                     $scope.error = result.Data.Message;
                 }

         });

     };

     $scope.cancel = function () {
         $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
     };

 }
]);
```

The problem is that $scope.topic doesn't update when I enter a value in the textbox. It shows the inital value from the model but it acts only as one-way binding (model -> view). Everything else works properly.

Is there something I forgot or is there a limitation of the ng-model directive?

Comment: Have you initialized your app and have you called your controller in your DOM?

Comment: I think that the problem is not in that concrete snippet. Can you show more html?

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/2uwTL/2/ - it shows the two way binding of the ng-model.

Comment: It should be in that snippet, because that the only place where it doesn't work. I'm using this example http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal and everything else in the modal works EXCEPT the 2 ways binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AngularUI Bootstrap $modal service is creating a transclusion scope for its modal windows. It means that there is one more scope between your controller and your template. This is why you need to use the "famous dot" in the `ng-model` expression, ex.:

In the controller:

```
$scope.topic = {value: 'initial'};
```

and in the template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="topic.value" />
```

Comment: It works! But I don't understand how making the value an object bypasses that additional scope.